# Bad file descriptor. WHY?

Tags: c, unix

I have searched everywhere and the only reason I know of that I would be getting a bad file descriptor for `fdUp[READ]` is if I had previously closed it. I don't believe I have done this and I cannot figure out why.

```
bool start_process(void) {
    int fdDown[2];
    int fdUp[2];
    FILE* in;
    FILE* out;

    if(pipe(fdDown) && pipe(fdUp)) {
        return false; //pipe failed
    }

    switch(fork()) {
        case -1:
            return false; //fork failed
        case 0:
            // child
            close(fdDown[WRITE]);
            dup2(fdDown[READ], STDIN_FILENO);
            close(fdDown[READ]);

            close(fdUp[READ]);
            dup2(fdUp[WRITE], STDOUT_FILENO);
            close(fdUp[WRITE]);

            execlp("./process", "process1", (char *) 0);
            return false; //exec failed
        default:
            //parent
            close(fdDown[READ]);
            out = fdopen(fdDown[WRITE], "w");

            close(fdUp[WRITE]);
            in = fdopen(fdUp[READ], "r");
            if(in==NULL) printf("%s\n", strerror(errno)); //BAD FILE DESCRIPTOR

            fprintf(out, "msg from parent\n");
            fflush(out);

            char buf[100];
            fgets(buf, 100, in);
            printf("%s", buf);

            wait(NULL);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your descriptors in `fdUp` are indeed invalid because of the way you initialize them.

```
   if(pipe(fdDown) && pipe(fdUp)) {
        return false; //pipe failed
    }
```

If `pipe(fdDown)` succeeds (i.e., returns 0) then `pipe(fdUp)` won't be executed at all (due to [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)).
You really want:

```
   if(pipe(fdDown) || pipe(fdUp)) {
        return false; //pipe failed
    }
```

---

Another way with better diagnostics could be:

```
   if(pipe(fdDown)) {
    perror("pipe: fdDown");
        return false;
    }


   if(pipe(fdUp)) {
    perror("pipe: fdUp");
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: THANK YOU, I can't believe I missed that